# Getting this error in CodeBlocks error: invalid types 'main()::fields[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++

Hi I am a begginer and I am going through "Beggining C++ through game programming" book (3rd edition). This is actually a code from the book, every line, and I get error that is in title. On line 24 (string theHint=HINT[choice][HINT];   //HINT FOR WORD)

I use CodeBlocks

```
     #include<iostream>
     #include<cstdlib>
     #include<string>
     #include<ctime>

     using namespace std;

     int main()
{

    enum fields {WORD, HINT, NUM_FIELDS};
    const int NUM_WORDS=5;
    const string WORDS[NUM_WORDS][NUM_FIELDS]=
    {
    {"wall", "Do you feel you're banging your head against something?"},
    {"glasses","These might help you see the answer."},
    {"labored","Going slowly, is it?"},
    {"persistent", "Keep at it."},
    {"jumble", "It's what the game is all about"}
    };

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    int choice=(rand()% NUM_WORDS);
    string theWord=WORDS[choice][WORD];  //WORD TO GUESS
    string theHint=HINT[choice][HINT];   //HINT FOR WORD

    string jumble=theWord;  //jumbled version of word
    int lenght=jumble.size();
    for(int i=0;i<lenght;++i)
    {
        int index1=(rand()%lenght);
        int index2=(rand()%lenght);
        char temp=jumble[index1];
        jumble[index1]=jumble[index2];
        jumble[index2]=temp;
    }
    //WELCOMING THE PLAYER
    cout<<"\t\t\tWelcome to Word Jumble!\n\n";
    cout<<"Unscramble the letters to make a word.\n";
    cout<<"Enter 'hint' for hint.\n";
    cout<<"Enter 'quit' to quit the game.\n\n";
    cout<<"The jumble is: "<<jumble;

    string guess;
    cout<<"\n\nYour guess: ";
    cin>>guess;

    //ENTERING THE GAME LOOP

    while((guess !=theWord)&& (guess!="quit"))
    {
        if(guess=="hint")
        {
            cout<<theHint;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Sorry that's not it.";
        }
        cout<<"\n\nYour guess: ";
        cin>>guess;
    }

    if(guess==theWord)
    {
        cout<<"\nThat's it! You guessed it!\n";
    }
    cout<<"\nThanks for playing. \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
WORDS[choice][HINT]
```

since `WORDS`, as an array, has both the words and the hints in it.